# Is it good practice to upload excel reports generated from database from application into google cloud for storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have migrated our Grails Application from on premise server to cloud(CF GCP).
In our application we have a crone job which generates a weekly excel report from database. It's big report of multiple sheets.

*It's important for business*

Anyways, we need to store this report somewhere so in future users can download it. As we were on old on premise server, we were storing on server itself.

But now we have moved over cloud.

**So I wanted to ask about should I store it in google cloud?**

**what are the best practises for things like these?**

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage has 9 "nine" of durability in regional mode and 11 "nine" in multi-regional mode.

If the file is important for the business, it's definitively a great place to store it. You can also activate the [versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) if you want to keep the previous versions (and a [lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to clean the oldest version, for example keep only the 5 latest versions).

But the storage is only one side of the concern that you should have. The retrieval is also important to be used by the business team.

If the users have Google Account, you can create a group and grant this group the permission to browse GCS and to download the objects. However, it's done through the Google Cloud console and not as clean as you can do with a dedicated UI. In addition, getting older versioned object can be tricky.

You can also offer a simple UI to download the file (you can use the [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to only provide the download URL and not load the file in your webservice).